# Как в python сгенерировать очень большие числа в массив?

Tags: python, массивы, алгоритм

Решаю задачу "Valid Perfect Square" на leetcode:

Учитывая положительное целое число num, верните true, если num является точным квадратом, или false в противном случае.

Идеальный квадрат — это целое число, которое является квадратом целого числа. Другими словами, это произведение некоторого целого числа само на себя.

Вы не должны использовать какие-либо встроенные библиотечные функции, такие как sqrt.

Вот так я ее решил:

```
class Solution(object):
def isPerfectSquare(self, num):
    """
    :type num: int
    :rtype: bool
    """
    arr = [i for i in range(1, num + 1)]
    low = 0
    high = len(arr) - 1
    while low <= high:
        mid = int((low + high) / 2)
        index = arr[mid]
        if index ** 2 == num:
            return True
        if index ** 2 > num:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1
    return False
```

Однако, когда num - очень большое число, например, 2000105819, то происходит очень долгое вычисление. Как быть?

Comment: Эээ, а зачем вам тут массив?

Comment: Не знаю что у вас за алгоритм, но у меня код сьел 20 гигабайт оперативной памяти) Что согласимся не слишком адекватно

Comment: Алгоритм-то то вполне жизнеспособный, но тут зачем-то создаётся массив на два миллиарда элементов… :facepalm:

Comment: Тут проблема не в генерации больших чисел, а генерации гигантского списка (который вообще не нужен).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Минимальные изменения позволяют сэкономить до 20, а то и 40 гигабайт памяти и примерно столько же времени.

Выкидывам к черту список, потому что единственное его предназначение здесь - получить число по индексу, которое равно индекс+1!

```
def isPerfectSquare(self, num):
    """
    :type num: int
    :rtype: bool
    """
    # arr = [i for i in range(1, num + 1)] <- выкидываем
    low = 0
    high = num - 1 # меняем len(arr) на num, потому что длина списка как раз равна заданному числу
    while low <= high:
        mid = int((low + high) / 2)
        # index = arr[mid] <- выкидываем
        if mid ** 2 == num: # меняем index на mid
            return True
        if mid ** 2 > num:  # меняем index на mid
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1
    return False
```

Comment: `int((low + high) / 2)` -> `(low + high) // 2`. Вы ограничиваете работу вещественным диапазоном, а алгоритм может намного, намного больше.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy не я. Все, что я изменил, я описал. Всё остальное как у автора.

Comment: все я понял спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Думаю бесполезно улучшать текущий алгоритм, лучше используйте [метод Ньютона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%9D%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0):

```
def isPerfectSquare(num):
    """
    :type num: int
    :rtype: bool
    """
    if num < 2:
        return True

    x = num // 2
    while x * x > num:
        x = (x + num // x) // 2

    return x * x == num
```

Comment: почему же бесполезно. Очень легко и просто он улучшается. Т.е. алгоритм даже улучшать не надо, поскольку бутылочное горлышко здесь - создание списка, а список в алгоритме вообще не используется.

Comment: Алгоритм ТС не использует длинное деление. Это может быть преимуществом для действительно больших чисел.